# Docker difference postgres:12 from postgres:12-alpine

Tags: postgresql, docker

Docker hub contains several versions(tag) of Postgres db such as:

- 12.3, 12, latest
- 12.3-alpine, 12-alpine, alpine
  -...

What is diff between postgres version 12.3 and 12.3-alpine?

Comment: If you click on those tags, you'll see the underlying Dockerfile. One is based on debian, the other on alpine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Alpine is a much smaller version of Linux, it results in a smaller container than the full postgres image. It is argued that because of its small size, alpine is also more secured. Although one disadvantage of alpine is that it contains a lot less functionality than a docker image running the full Linux OS.

Comment: Why not always using the alpine version?! Fewer functionalities but enough to run postgres anyway.  Who tries to run something else in the image?!

Comment: It depends on personal preferences. I personally prefer to run Alpine whenever possible but it can be more complicated sometimes as some package could be missing, making the creation of the appropriate Docker image harder.

Answer (score 13):

- `postgres:12.3` is based on [**Debian**](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/88173efa530f1a174a7ea311c5b6ee5e383f68bd/12/Dockerfile) :
- `postgres:12.3-alpine` is based on [**Alpine**](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/b1f60bd4f88fa2f82aaaa304dc1476a26938cb38/12/alpine/Dockerfile)

Mainly the image sizes and contents differ:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You should be very careful when choosing a docker image for your database. The fact is that PostgreSQL in Alpine and Debian use a different collation.

Some Alpine images use musl library version (1.1.16) that does not support LC_COLLATE, so despite settings LANG variable, sorting data will be bytewise (C).

LC_COLLATE should be added to musl version 1.1.17

But this can create a problem of disastrous proportions: as soon as musl supports LC_COLLATE, all Postgres VARCHAR indexes will break.

See more discussion in:

- https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/273
- https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/327
- ...

I tried it myself:

FROM postgres:13-alpine

```
postgres=# select 'a' > 'A';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'a' < 'A';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

FROM postgres:13

```
postgres=# select 'a' > 'A';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'a' < 'A';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Note that there is now a workaround with **Postgres 15**. See https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/1004#issuecomment-1280559846 and https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#locale-customization. I just tried your examples `select 'a' > 'A'` and `select 'a' < 'A'` with **postgres:15-alpine** initialized with `-e LANG=en-US.utf8 -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=en-US"` and it indeed works as expected!